# Org agenda hide empty sections (searches)

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have multiple sections in my agenda, and I have one that I want to see on top if it is not empty. But if it is empty its just taking up space and I'd like to hide it. I tried searching for this but couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-06/msg00266.html

```
  (defun org-agenda-delete-empty-blocks ()
    "Remove empty agenda blocks.
  A block is identified as empty if there are fewer than 2
  non-empty lines in the block (excluding the line with
  `org-agenda-block-separator' characters)."
    (when org-agenda-compact-blocks
      (user-error "Cannot delete empty compact blocks"))
    (setq buffer-read-only nil)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let* ((blank-line-re "^\\s-*$")
             (content-line-count (if (looking-at-p blank-line-re) 0 1))
             (start-pos (point))
             (block-re (format "%c\\{10,\\}" org-agenda-block-separator)))
        (while (and (not (eobp)) (forward-line))
          (cond
           ((looking-at-p block-re)
            (when (< content-line-count 2)
              (delete-region start-pos (1+ (point-at-bol))))
            (setq start-pos (point))
            (forward-line)
            (setq content-line-count (if (looking-at-p blank-line-re) 0 1)))
           ((not (looking-at-p blank-line-re))
            (setq content-line-count (1+ content-line-count)))))
        (when (< content-line-count 2)
          (delete-region start-pos (point-max)))
        (goto-char (point-min))
        ;; The above strategy can leave a separator line at the beginning
        ;; of the buffer.
        (when (looking-at-p block-re)
          (delete-region (point) (1+ (point-at-eol))))))
    (setq buffer-read-only t))

  (add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook #'org-agenda-delete-empty-blocks)
```